# How to increase number of regions in an HBase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have created a table in HBase with a pre split of 8 regions, with HexStringSplit as spliting algorithm. Now I want to increase the number of regions, without destroying the existing table and the data in it. The command with which I created the pre split was

`create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}`

As it is I cannot execute this command again for increasing the number of regions. Is there any command present for updating the number of regions in an existing table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please notice that the command you provide creates 15 regions, not 8: `create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}`

You can split regions with the split command:

```
hbase(main):001:0> split

Here is some help for this command:
Split entire table or pass a region to split individual region.  With the
second parameter, you can specify an explicit split key for the region.
Examples:
    split 'tableName'
    split 'regionName' # format: 'tableName,startKey,id'
    split 'tableName', 'splitKey'
    split 'regionName', 'splitKey'
```

You should use `split 'regionName', 'splitKey'` or `split 'tableName', 'splitKey'`, just do not forget to provide the proper SplitKey (the mid one) to each region to ensure even distribution. You can see the current regions at http://your-hbase-master:60010/table.jsp?name=your-table

i.e: if you have a region with StartKey 20000000 and EndKey 40000000 your splitKey would be 30000000, or, if you have a region with StartKey 20000000 and EndKey 30000000 your SplitKey would be 28000000 (remember, it's HEX)

Please try it first with test tables until you feel confident enough with the process.