# Modify existing table split in hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase table created with 20 pre-created splits based on row key prefix. Now I want to increase the number of splits to 50 using the same method. Is there any way to do that in HBase? Dropping and re-creating the table with new splits is not an option as I have some hundreds of millions of rows in it and I want to retain it as it is and only increase the splits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have found an answer that is close enough as mentioned in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29606448/6162224. I'm posting this as the answer now and accept it after a few days if I cannot find one that enables creation of multiple new splits in a single command.